# No such module 'Eureka' error while using 'GooglePlacesRow' in Pods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, swift5

Previously in project, Eureka and GooglePlacesRow were directly embedded. 
Now, I am trying to update the Eureka and GooglePlacesRow to latest version using pods. 
But this is causing error as "No such module 'Eureka'" only in the files related to `GooglePlacesRow`.

```
Xcode version 10.2.1
Swift Version 5
Eureka Version 5.0.0
GooglePlacesRow 3.2.0
```

I tried the following things:

- Clean and build
- Deleting Derived data and then build
- Checked for Framework Search path as well.

My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'ProjectName' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ProjectName
  pod 'SnapKit', '~> 4.2.0'
  pod 'KeychainAccess', '~> 3.2.0'
  pod 'Just', '~> 0.7.1'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 5.0.0'
  pod 'PKHUD', '~> 5.2.1'
  pod 'GSMessages', '~> 1.7.2'
  pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.15.0'
  pod 'Pages', '~> 2.0.2'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '~> 6.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.20.2'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.20.2'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash', '~> 5.20.02'
  pod 'GradientCircularProgress', :git => 
  'https://github.com/keygx/GradientCircularProgress'
  pod 'Zip', '~> 1.1.0'
  pod 'GRDB.swift', '~> 3.7.0'
  pod 'Localize-Swift', '~> 2.0.0'
  #pod 'Eureka', '~> 5.0.0'
  pod 'GooglePlacesRow', '~> 3.2.0'


end
```

Thanks in Advance ☺️

Comment: can you share your podfile so we have a better understanding of the issue ?

Comment: @Olympiloutre added screenshot of podfile. GooglePlacesRow will also install Eureka and GooglePlaces.

Comment: you should copy/paste the pod instead of a screenshot, youll have better chance someone understand and help you to solve your problem quickly

Comment: @Olympiloutre Thank you for the suggestion. I have edited the question and added it as a text. I will keep in mind this thing while posting the question

Comment: why the `Eureka` line is commented btw?

Comment: GooglePlacesRow will install the Eureka automatically, so no need to add it. https://github.com/EurekaCommunity/GooglePlacesRow

Comment: have you tried: (1) commenting `pod 'GooglePlacesRow'` (2) run `pod install`, which will deinstall GooglePlaces, (3) uncoment `pod 'GooglePlacesRow'` and (4) re-run `pod install` ? - This would force the pod and its dependencies to be re-downloaded

Comment: or `pod cache clear --all` then `pod install` should do the trick

Comment: Yes, I have tried with that as well, the same error is happening